# Asterisk Realtime and External SIP table

Tags: authentication, external, sip, asterisk, sip-server

I'm having spleepless night thanks to Asterisk Realtime. 
I have some trouble understanding the documentation ( like http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip ). Too many tables, many parameters, fragmented informations, no exhaustive tutorial.

I have simply to auto-register some users from an external MySQL's table ( id, user, chatkey ).

Which are the columns i HAVE to set to get it work? If there where simply a user and password column, I would have matched them with my.user and my.chatkey, but now I'm very confused.

Is there any side effects using VIEWS instead table + triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You have set ALL columns. Minimum set is something like type,username, host,name,nat,allow,disallow.

You can do it using mysql view from your current tables.But if you do so, you have use cache of realtime friends or organize contact update(update&store of all fields below&including  ipaddr). Otherwise your setup will not able determine where your sip devices.

I don't understand your issues. Wiki is very clear. For sip auth you need only one table  sip_buddies

and need put in /etc/asterisk/extconfig.conf

```
sipusers => mysql,general,sip_buddies
sippeers => mysql,general,sip_buddies
```

note, general - name of already setuped(in /etc/asterisk/res_mysql.conf) database connection.

From your question i see you not understanding asterisk internals, so i recommending you read Orely's book "Asterisk the future of telephony" or hire expert. Otherwise resulting application will be not scalable and probably will work strange.